# Can Thomson sampling be used for better results in a 1 player-MCTS

Tags: monte-carlo, multiarmed-bandit

I made a [Monte Carlo tree search (MCTS) algorithm for the travelling salesman problem](https://github.com/Butanium/monte-carlo-tree-search-and-TSP) inspired by [this paper](http://sasimi.jp/new/sasimi2016/files/archive/pdf/p352_R4-14.pdf) which uses UCB1.

When I was digging to see where does the UCB1 formula comes from, I read [this article](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/01/23/the-multi-armed-bandit-problem-and-its-solutions.html#hoeffdings-inequality) which then introduces the Thompson sampling.

I was wondering if in a MCTS for a problem like the TSP, the Thompson sampling could be used (Most of the usage I saw of Thompson sampling with MCTS were with in Bernoulli configuration for exemple [this one in which UCB1 performs better](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261280719_Comparison_of_different_selection_strategies_in_Monte-Carlo_Tree_Search_for_the_game_of_Tron)) and if it would be more efficient than the UCB1.